# Javascript array that inside of map appears empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
let arr1 =[{name:'mani',age:2},{name:'raj',age:2},{name:'s',age:1}];

let test = new Map();

for(const EI of arr1){

    if( !test.has(EI.age)){
        test.set(EI.age,new Array());
     
    }
    
    test.set(EI.age,test.get(EI.age).push(EI) );
     
}
```

when i console log this map, the array is empty for all the keys.

but it works as expected for the below code

```
let arr1 =[3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,8];

let test = new Map();

for(const EI of arr1){

    if( !test.has(EI)){
        test.set(EI,1);
        continue;
    }

    test.set(EI,test.get(EI) + 1);

}
```

Even i tried taking copy of array  test.set(EI,[test.get(EI)].push(1) ) still get empty array only

[here the result is as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxSZ1.png)

[array is empty here .....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sopzx.png)

Comment: i know other ways to get it as expected, but i dont know why its not working in this way, thanks in advance for the explaination

Comment: If I understand your problem right, you need to remove the `continue` statement.

Comment: `if( !test.has(EI))` should be `if( !test.has(EI.age)){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` returns the length, not the array.

so after this call:

```js
test.set(EI.age,test.get(EI.age).push(EI) );
```

The map entry for `EI.age` isn’t an array. It’s a number.

And I would expect subsequent push calls for that entry to error.

And unless it’s your intention to skip the first occurrence you should remove the `continue` after creating the empty array.

Comment: You also can use `test.set(EI.age,(test.get(EI.age) | []).push(EI) );` and remove first `if` statement at all

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand seeing your code, you're trying to have `test` object with keys being the age and value being an array of whosoever is of that age. This should work for that case :

```js
let arr1 =[{name:'mani',age:2},{name:'raj',age:2},{name:'s',age:1}];

let test = {};

for(const EI of arr1){
    if(!test[EI.age]){
        test[EI.age] =  [];
    }
    
    test[EI.age].push(EI.name);
     // Or optionally, push the whole object instead
     // test[EI.age].push(EI);
}
```